# Does Noctis take fall damage?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

In many games, falling from a decent height will damage the player. I've fallen from maybe 20 or 30 feet and taken no damage, so I'm wondering if it's even possible to take fall damage. Whenever I find a nice cliff to try to jump from, I'm prevented from potentially killing myself by a nice, invisible wall. Is there a certain height threshold that if I fall from, I'll take damage? Or is there just no fall damage in this game?

Apologies if this is like previous Final Fantasy titles. The last Final Fantasy I played was VII and there was no such thing as falling in that game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can take fall damage.

In the quest line for Dino at Guldan Quay, you have to find an ore outcrop. I fell off the cliff this was on top of and took 243 damage.

I didn't jump off the cliff, which might be a contributing factor, as a jump from height seems to produce a landing roll.

*Edit*
<strike>I have been unable to reproduce this in any way since.</strike>

*Further edit*
This is reproducable easily by jumping over the top tier of stairs on a watchtower. I have included a video of this.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with story progression on that? Cause I remember taking fall damage falling off that exact cliff.

Comment: The fall damage seems to be capped though because I did a really high jump in Duscae near the center of the map and it damaged me really less than expected. It might not be directly proportionnal.

Comment: An important note is that you can get fall damage by warp striking something that is very high in the air. Definitely a pain in combat. Though further warping will I believe allow you to avoid the damage.

Comment: Also worth noting is that you can avoid fall damage by warping just before you land.